# Minimum braking distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

Suppose we are biking at a constant speed, is the minimum braking distance the same whether we apply the brakes on the front wheel or the back wheel?

I admit this is a homework problem, but I can't think of a reason why there would be a difference...

(Some numbers were given: Distance between the wheels is 1m, the center of mass is exactly between the wheels at 1m of height, the static friction is 1.0, the bike is at a constant speed of 10m/s)

We are currently going through torque, moment of inertia, angular momentum...So I guess we were supposed to use these to solve the problem...

I initially wanted to solve it using the conservation of energy, i.e. the kinetic energy would be converted into heat caused by friction, which actually works, but i guess that's not how I'm supposed to do this problem.

Comment: At first glance, I think when you brake with the front brakes, which are in front of the center of mass, the weight of the bike acts like a lever, pushing the tire further down, increasing the friction. So the highest friction should be when the back wheel is just about to lift off. This would make sense as exercise 3 is also about lever force.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum braking force is the maximum possible static friction force between the tire and the road. That force is $F_{max}=\mu_{s}N$ where $\mu_s$ is the coefficient of static friction and $N$ is the portion of the weight of the car that is supported by the tire.

So it depends on which wheel is supporting more of the weight of the vehicle and its occupants and/or has a larger value of $\mu_s$.  Another possible factor may be limitations in the design of the front and rear brakes, but I'm not sure since I have no expertise in this area.

Hope this helps.